# Attribute in base controller not triggering in unit tests in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I understand this is not the correct way to unit test but we have a ActionFilterAttribute on our base controller that never gets fired during our unit tests. I know we should test it independently but we want to integrate it into our overall testing end to end.

```
  [ThemeModel]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public MyModel Context { get; set; }    
}
```

How do I integrate my attribute when we run the test from the inherited controller? I understand attributes are not tied in with the controller and part of the mvc framework.

thanks...

Comment: You have to create an integration test which use self host server

Answer (score 0):

Two options I think. 1 is what you're doing already, and I wouldn't change it. 2 is the answer to your problem. I believe it's good to have both.

1. Keep your unit tests for the controller and the filters separate. This is proper for UT, since your controller and filters shouldn't have hard dependencies on each other. In this way you will know that each works properly on its own (Single Responsibility Principle).
2. Create a separate set of tests that implement `HttpContextBase`. I assume you already have a mock `HttpContextBase` to do session or cookie mocks, so I'll just highlight the main things for your particular filter. (If you don't, just search for `HttpContextBase` and unit testing).

   `public class MockHttpContext : HttpContextBase
   {
       public MockHttpContext()
       {
           MockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
           // .. etc ..
           var actionExecutingContext = new Mock<ActionExecutingContext>();
           actionExecutingContext.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(this);
           var filter = new ThemeModelAttribute();
           filter.OnActionExecuting(actionExecutingContext.Object);
           // OnActionExecuted has similar setup if needed.
       }
   }`

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Check that attribute `ThemeModel` has `AttributeUsage(Inherited = true)`

Answer (score -1):

You should test your filter separately. Create required controller context objects and user "filter.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext.Object);" like syntax.

Comment: I need to integrate it altogether otherwise I need to rewrite all the tests from a hand-me-down project. I will test the action filter independently but other tests are breaking because of this.